# Exporting multiple Excel Ranges to PowerPoint Notes Page using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, shapes

Is it possible to export multiple excel ranges to a single PowerPoint Notes Page using VBA?

I have managed to export a specified range to a named slide, but cannot export multiple ranges to the same slide note - the first is always overwritten

If I add multiple shapes, then only the latest one shows.  I don't seem to be able to position the shape, so it always writes over the top of the previous one

Comment: Can you show some code?